# How to use forech condition for List in Android

Tags: java, android, list, kotlin

In my application i have one `List` and into this `List` i have one `integer` value.
I want check post **`id`** wit this `integer` of `List`, if this **`id`** is equal, i should change UI.
I write below codes, but in my codes just change last item UI.

**My code:**

```
for (int i = 0; i <= data.getBasket().size() - 1; i++) {
    Log.e("BooksIdLog", bookId + " - " + data.getBasket().get(i).getBookId());
    if (bookId == data.getBasket().get(i).getBookId()) {
        detailPage_bottomSheetPrintVersion.setBackground(context.getResources()
                .getDrawable(R.drawable.bg_rounded_stroke_red));
        detailPage_bottomSheetPrintVersion.setText(getString(R.string.removeFromBasket));
        detailPage_bottomSheetPrintVersion.setTextColor(context.getResources()
                .getColor(R.color.red));
        detailPage_bottomSheetPrintVersion.setOnClickListener(view -> 
                presenter.callRemoveBookBasketApi(apiHash, userToken, bookId)
            );
    } else {
        detailPage_bottomSheetPrintVersion.setBgColor(context.getResources()
                .getColor(R.color.platinumGray));
        detailPage_bottomSheetPrintVersion.setText(getString(R.string.printVersion));
        detailPage_bottomSheetPrintVersion.setTextColor(context.getResources()
                .getColor(android.R.color.black));
        detailPage_bottomSheetPrintVersion.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            presenter.callAddBookBasketApi(apiHash, userToken, bookId);
        });
    }
}
```

**Data fields :**

```
data class Basket(
    @SerializedName("basket_id")
    val basketId: Int = 0, // 61
    @SerializedName("book_id")
    val bookId: Int = 0, // 156570
    @SerializedName("count")
    val count: Int = 0, // 1
    @SerializedName("id")
    val id: Int = 0, // 156570
    @SerializedName("inventory")
    val inventory: Int = 0, // 0
    @SerializedName("price_of_each_book")
    val priceOfEachBook: String = "", // 0
    @SerializedName("title")
    val title: String = ""
)
```

**For example :**
I have 3 item into this `List` and this 3 items ids is = **155060** - **155070** - **154030** , when go to detail page activity just update UI in this id **154030** not all of ids !

How can i fix it?

Comment: What data type is in `data`? Something like `Book`?

Comment: @deHaar, please see my update post

Comment: OK, so you are using Kotlin, please update your question tags accordingly...

Comment: what getBasket() returns? List?

Comment: @deHaar, ok but can you help me?

Comment: @MuhammadNoman, yes . return `listOf()` . `val basket: List<Basket> = listOf(),`

Comment: You are updatin only one UI item "detailPage_bottomSheetPrintVersion".  What else do you want to change? For me its seems like you updating only this item

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to use `forEach` instead of a classic `for`-loop for a `MutableList<Basket>` (for example), then you can do it in Kotlin like this:

```
data.getBasket().forEach(basket -> {
    Log.e("BooksIdLog", bookId + " - " + basket.getBookId());
    if (bookId == basket.getBookId()) {
        ...
    } else {
        ...
    }
}
```

But I think your loop is working correctly...

My guess is you are not properly updating the value of `bookId` which is used for comparison. Check where it is declared, defined and used...

Comment: @DrKingo in Java, you can do a different kind of a `for`-each loop: `for (Basket basket : data.getBasket()) { ... }`